# std::tuple conflicting with boost::python::tuple when compiling with cl.exe

Tags: python, c++, c++11, boost

I am trying to compile the triangulation generation package [MeshPy](https://documen.tician.de/meshpy/index.html) which uses Boost.Python to interface Python and C++. During compilation i recieve the following error in several places in `foreign_array_wrap.hpp`:

```
[my home folder]\desktop\dist\meshpy-2014.1\src\cpp\foreign_array_wrap.hpp(143): error C2872: 'tuple': ambiguous symbol
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\INCLUDE\tuple(204): note: could be 'std::tuple'
[my home folder]\Desktop\boost_1_60_0\boost/python/tuple.hpp(32): note: or       'boost::python::tuple'
```

It would appear that the namespaces `boost::python` and `std::` are in conflict. However, I've managed to compile the exact same version of MeshPy without a problem on my MacBook running Yosemite.

Any ideas? Please ask if anything is unclear.

Comment: Do you have `using namespace std;` somewhere in your code?

Comment: It's probably the `using namespace boost::python;`. Rewrite the code to explicitly use `boost::python::tuple` wherever a plain `tuple` is used. (lines 56, 91, 150, 152).

Comment: Actually, I just noticed that that library has `using namespace boost::python;` in the global namespace of a header file. I would recommend you stop using the library. It can't possibly be any good.

Comment: This is precisely what namespaces avoid. You probably have a `using namespace` somewhere which needs to be removed and fully qualified namespace names specified.